# what is the best way to integrate asp.net core multi page application (enterprise app) with react.js?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have read many articles and seen many videos about the integration between asp.net core with React.js, however these ways of integration use many installed packages like

- React.Web.Mvc4
- JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.Native.win-x86
- JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.Native.win-x64
- JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8
- React.Web
- react.js

and all these packages make the execution more complex.

for that reason, I thought I would post this question to see how other developers use the React.js library in the asp.net framework in a lite way.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Well i have a project in asp.net core razor pages where i had a page that needed a little bit of interactivty so i used react js.

What i did was add the react js cdn to my layout page, added babel with react js presets and compiled my jsx files to my wwwroot/js folder.

After that in my razor page i referenced that js file and it worked perfectly.

If you need more help i can put more details here.

Comment: I would be interested in more details and steps